# Advice on upgrading Emacs (22 -> 24), and also about GUI vs console/terminal

Tags: r, emacs

I'm using a Macbook Pro (Snow Leopard, 10.6.8) and have been a regular emacs user for the past  few months. I'm trying to install a modified version of Emacs 24.2 [provided here](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/) to utilize Emacs Speaks Statistics (ESS) from the [downloads page](http://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download). I currently have 22.1.1:

```
M-x emacs-version
GNU Emacs 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin) of 2011-06-07 on b1030.apple.com
```

I installed the emacs linked earlier, put it in Applications, and set this in .bashrc:

```
alias emacs="/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw"
```

So it seems like it's working correctly as I wrote and successfully ran a short R program.

```
M-x emacs-version
GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2012-08-27 on bob.porkrind.org
```

Is this the usual way to upgrade to a "newer version" of Emacs? Sorry if this question seems trivial, but I've never done this before (I typically used emacs on a different computer) and the Installation step on the previous website consists of just one sentence. The all-in-one installation method also isn't explained in the official [documentation](http://ess.r-project.org/ess.pdf).

---

A brief side note while I was searching on the web: I believe calling 'emacs file_name' should open a GUI version, while 'emacs -nw file_name' is the console, so I remain using the terminal. But on my Mac, using emacs has the same effect as using emacs -nw. In other words, I can't get a GUI or separate window to show up. Can anyone confirm that [this Super User question has the 'correct' answer](https://superuser.com/questions/278850/open-a-new-window-for-emacs-from-terminal-in-mac)? (I don't really have a problem with this, as I hate having another pop-up window, but it would be nice to know for completeness.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Emacs that comes with Mac OS X `/usr/bin/emacs` does not have a graphical interface, just the terminal one, so calling `emacs` is the same as `emacs -nw`.

Your upgraded Emacs by default starts with the graphical interface, so you need to specify `-nw` to force it to use the terminal.

There is no "usual" way to upgrade OS X's default Emacs (i.e. Apple does not provide an upgraded Emacs); what you've done is fine.  Or you could install a binary from http://emacsformacosx.com/ or use a package manager like homebrew.